# How to dynamically update a defaultdict with placeholders

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having issues trying to dynamically update a dictionary as I add values to keys.

The code below essentially function to loop through subdirectories, then loops through files in each subdirectory. Each file is then simply parsed and data is added to a defaultdict dictionary. The data consists of two fields: chrLocation (keys) and editRatio (values). What I am trying to accomplish here is to accommodate for those keys that were not initially added from the first file. Note that the keys are unique in each file but there can be duplicates among other files. Likewise, there can be keys that appear in, say file7 that was not in the first 6 files. I'd like to show this in my dictionary by have 6 placeholders (zeros) before the first key entry.

```
dataDict = defaultdict(list)
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(rootdir + "/out/"):
    for d in dirs:
        print "Processing: ", d
        colNames.append(d + "_" + sampOriginDict[d])
            for editingFile in os.listdir(rootdir + "/out/" + d):
                eFile = open(rootdir + "/out/" + d + "/" + editingFile, 'r')
                for line in eFile:
                    # only care about 3 fields (chromosome, location and editratio)
                    chromosome, location, x1, x2, x3, x4, editRatio, x5, x6, x7 = line.split("\t")
                    chrLocation = chromosome + "_" + location
                    dataDict[chrLocation].append(editRatio)
```

Brief output is shown below for looping through 2 files:

```
chr17_37916827 ['0.15']
chr16_29681751 ['0.1']
chr6_150045787 ['0.33']
chr10_75538108 ['0.43', '0.71']
chr15_64447436 ['0.5', '0.5']
chr16_15794023 ['0.21', '0.18']
```

As of now the code does not accommodate for placeholders. So, by looking at the output, I'm not sure if that '0.15' came from the first file or the second.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: I've added a conditional to check if a key already exists and this was the resulting output:

```
chr17_37916827 ['File2']
chr16_29681751 ['File1']
chr6_150045787 ['File2']
chr10_75538108 ['File1', 'exists']
chr15_64447436 ['File1', 'exists']
chr16_15794023 ['File1', 'exists']
```

Code:

```
if chrLocation in dataDict.keys(): 
    dataDict[chrLocation].append("exists")
else:
    dataDict[chrLocation].append(d)
```

I'd like to achieve the output:

```
chr17_37916827 ['0', 'File2']
chr16_29681751 ['File1', '0']
chr6_150045787 ['0', 'File2']
chr10_75538108 ['File1', 'exists']
chr15_64447436 ['File1', 'exists']
chr16_15794023 ['File1', 'exists']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way to do this using your current approach**

Okay so you either need to know how many files there are at the start and change values in each list by index or keep count and then iterate over your `defaultdict` and append placeholder values to any below that count...

Example of the former:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * 7)
```

And then for the current `i`,

```
dataDict[chrLocation][i] = editRatio
```

But I wouldn't suggest this as it doesn't sound necessary to keep these placeholders hanging around.

---

**Accomplish the same goal in a different way**

Unless I misunderstood, the goal is really just to be able to tell which files have a given key. Maybe use a structure like,

```
dataDict = defaultdict(dict)
```

and where you were doing `dataDict[chrLocation].append(editRatio)` instead do,

```
dataDict[chrLocation][editingFile] = editRatio
```

You can then check if you have a value for a location and file,

```
try:
    print(dataDict['chr10_75538108']['File1'])
except KeyError:
    print('Nope!')
```

Or just append tuples of `(editingFile, editRatio)` to a list if you aren't going to be doing lookups using location and file.

Comment: Modifying my current approach to initialized the defaultdict first seems the easiest. I've adapted it to my code and it works perfect now. Thank you very much!